# GET the searched value with jquery

Tags: jquery, url, search, get

I have searched long but cant find how can I get with jquery with GET searched value from url[image: question].

Please help me.

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/02/jquery-how-to-get-querystring-value-get.html

Comment: Thx but it cant help with my issue

Comment: search for keywords: "GET parameter javascript", using your favorite search engine

Comment: use `GetParameterValues('searchPrice_text')`, it will work based on @ShoaibChikate solution

Comment: I need some code that will get the searched value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery,you can use native javascript like this:

```
var Request = {
    QueryString : function (item) {
        var svalue = location.search.match(new RegExp("[\?\&]" + item + "=([^\&]*)(\&?)","i"));
        return svalue?svalue[1]:svalue;
    },

    queryAllString : function() {
        var urlLocation = location.href;
        var startPosition = urlLocation.indexOf("?");
        if (startPosition < 0) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return urlLocation.slice(startPosition);
        }
    }
}
```